# click function to only execute on certain data names

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I have this `click:function` for an interactive [**jQuery US map**](http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/).

The below defines the "active color states" -- the color states turn after being clicked. I would like to alter to only work / execute on a few states I choose. Every state has a data.name with it's abbreviation. *Eg.* `'OH' 'CA' 'TX" 'NY`' etc. The active color removes upon click another states (as is below) I just need the ability to have this work with ONLY my select chosen states, not all 50.

```
click: function(c, l) {
    $("#map > svg > path").each(function() {
            $(this).css("fill", "")
        }),
        $("#" + l.name).css("fill", "#ffc600"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array with allowed states `var clickable = ['OH','CA','TX','NY'];` and then use `indexOf` to see if the clicked state is in it..

Try

```
click: function(c,l){
  var node = $(l.shape.node),
      siblings = node.siblings('path');

  siblings.css('fill','');
  if (clickable.indexOf(l.name) > -1){
    // select it
    node.css('fill','green');
  }
}
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/dPLGVg

---

You could do the styling with CSS, though
(*example requires browsers the support the `classList` property*)

```
click: function(c,l){
  var active = $(l.shape.node)
                 .siblings('.selected')
                 .get(0);

  // if there is an selected path
  if (active) {
    // de-select it
    active.classList.remove('selected');
  }
  // if clicked node is in list of clickables
  if (clickable.indexOf(l.name) > -1){
    // select it
    l.shape.node.classList.add('selected')
  }
}
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/dPLGRg

Answer (score 1):

How about using the configuration options of the USMap and using its `stateSpecificStyles`

```
$('#map').usmap({
  stateSpecificStyles: {
    'MD': {fill: '#ffc600'},
    'VA': {fill: '#ffc600'}
  } 
});
```

You could then collect all clicked states and update the `stateSpecificStyles` accordingly:

```
var clickedStates = [];  // array with states that have been clicked

click: function(c, l) {
    // if state was clicked before no need for update - so check
    if (clickedStates.indexOf(l.name) < 0) {
        // remember clicked state
        clickedStats.push(l.name);
        // build new state styles
        var styles = {};
        for (var i=clickedStats.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            styles[clickedStats[i]] = {fill: '#ffc600'};
        }
        // pass new style object to map
        $('#map').usmap({
          stateSpecificStyles: styles 
        });
    }
}
```

That should change the color than of each map clicked and if you want to implement a different logic (clicking CA colors CA, NY and TX) then you simply add to the clickedStates array.

Hope that helped